# CSS code works for one part but not other

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to color second column. I have code in a.js file:

```
if($data == 0 ){
   $display.after("<tr id='after'><td></td><td>First Part</td></tr>");
   return; 
}

$display.after("<tr id='after'><td></td><td><table>..Second Part...</table></td></tr>");
```

In a.css file:

```
#after td td {
   background-color: red; 
}
```

The second part changes colour, but first part does not change.

If I use:

```
#after td + td {
    background-color: red; 
}
```

or if I add a table in first part. Both work, why?

Comment: Why are you using the td selector 2 times?

Comment: I would like to color second column only.

Comment: Oh allright. Wait a second :) Will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style only the second td in your `#after` you could use this code:

```
#after td:nth-child(2)
{
   background-color: red; 
}
```

EDIT:

This won't work for IE8 < so in that case you could use @mr.aliens answer.

```
#after td + td /* Selects td adjacent to another td */
{
   background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: Note: This will fail in IE8

Comment: Yes, I know. Will add a fix to my answer.

Comment: Class is not req here, as I gave a solution in my answer, `+` will work kwel :)

Comment: Hehe thanks, I didn't wanted an upvote, I just wanted to say was that you can add that solution to your answer, it is an accepted one so people will refer yours

Comment: hehe now you got me :) well will upvote yours too, it's good solution but I didn't suggested as I thought he wanted to target a single td nested inside `#after`

Comment: Happy we can help people together on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong selector there.. if you want to apply background on all the `td` nested inside `#after` you need to use

```
#after td {
   background-color: red; 
}
```

Or you can apply the background to the `tr` element as well

```
#after {
   background-color: red; 
}
```

The 1st selector you are using their will select the `td` element nested inside another `td` element which are further nested inside an element having an id `#after` which is semantically incorrect.

The second selector you are using selects the adjacent element. So that will select `td` which is adjacent to another `td` which are further nested inside an element having `#after`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Euc7z/)

Comment: I would like to change second column’s colour, that is why #after td td.

Comment: The problems is that I don't understand why #after td td works for Second Part. What is difference between #after td td and #after td + td for Second Part.

Comment: @user1064993 I explained both in my answer, did you read that?

Answer (score 1):

**Space:** It is the descendant selector

```
#after td td {  //affects  tds within #after td
   background-color: red; 
}
```

**+ Sign:**

It is Adjacent sibling combinator. It combines two sequences of simple selectors having the same parent and the second one must come IMMEDIATELY after the first.

```
#after td + td {  //affects only the next td of #after td
    background-color: red; 
}
```

This might help you.

```
#after td {  //affects all the td in #after 
    background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: For Second Part: is there any difference between #after td td and #after td table ?